# how to union the element whose type is map of a vector to a map in scala?

Tags: scala

I have a vector of Maps as below, how to convert them into one map?

```
scala> (1 to 100).takeWhile(_<10).map{x=>val y=x+1;Map(x->y)}
res8: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int]] = Vector(Map(1 -> 2), Map(2 -> 3), Map(3 -> 4), Map(4 -> 5), Map(5 -> 6), Map(6 -> 7), Map(7 -> 8), Map(8 -> 9), Map(9 -> 10))
```

Comment: if you need transform result than res8.flatten.toMap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not need to turn each element into a map, then the tuples can go straight to a Map like this

```
(1 to 100).takeWhile(_<10).map{x=>val y=x+1;x->y}.toMap
```

If you do have to go from a Seq of maps, as shown in the question then fold may be used to join the maps together

```
val v = (1 to 100).takeWhile(_<10).map{x=>val y=x+1;Map(x->y)}
v.fold(Map.empty)((a,b) => a ++ b )
```

Fold works by starting with an initial value, in this case Map.empty and then performing an operation on that value and then keeping the result of that op to be used with the next element of the sequence.  It then repeats for every element in the sequence.  In the example that I have given, the operation was (a,b) => a ++ b, where a starts as the initial value and then is the result of each iteration and b is the current element being considered from the sequence being folded over.